# Setting negative elements Eigen SparseVector C++

Tags: c++, eigen, eigen3

What is the most efficient way to set all negative values in an Eigen SparseVector to zero?

I have a SparseVector w/ ~1000000 elements w/ very few nonzero entries.  I need to set ones that are negative to zero.  Iterating over the whole vector takes way too much time.  Is there a more efficient way to do this?

Comment: do the remapping as the vector is loaded.

Comment: I'm an eigen novice.  How would you go about doing this?

Comment: Are you OK with working with the compressed form of the matrix once you’ve removed negative none-zero entries? If so, maybe `prune()` can help you out.

Comment: As dfri wrote, the method `prune()` is what you're looking, it's easy to find in the [doc](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1SparseVector.html#af094e30271da69f865b5d97f338f81d1).

Comment: Prune didn't work for me.  I tried both prune and pruned w/ various values.  It seems prune only eliminates near zero values.  I figured it out by just using inner iterator.  Posting the solution below.  Thank you everyone.

Comment: ah right only `SparseMatrix::prune` supports custom predicate: `mat.prune([](double x) { return r<0; });`

Comment: Oh cool.  I will try that out.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
for (Eigen::SparseVector<double, Eigen::RowMajor>::InnerIterator it(fullScan); it; ++it) {
    if (it.value() < 0) {
        fullScan.coeffRef(it.index()) = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: You can then call `fullScan.prune(0.0);` to remove them, otherwise `fullScan` will still contains explicit zeros.

Comment: That is exactly what I did.  I just didn't include it in the code snippet here.

Answer (score 0):

For `SparseMatrix` you could actually use `prune` with a custom functor (which must return true for values which shall be kept):

```
mat.prune([](int, int, const double& val) { return val >= 0.0; });
```

Not sure why this is not available for SparseVector, though.